# Is it that I can't edit an AKS cluster on Azure?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-active-directory, azure-aks

Now I want to integrate Azure AD with AKS as [Integrate Azure Active Directory with Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/aad-integration).

It is necessary to set these attributes to the AKS cluster:

- aad-server-app-id
- aad-server-app-secret
- aad-client-app-id
- aad-tenant-id

It can do like this:

```
az aks create \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name myAKSCluster \
  --generate-ssh-keys \
  --aad-server-app-id b1536b67-29ab-4b63-b60f-9444d0c15df1 \
  --aad-server-app-secret wHYomLe2i1mHR2B3/d4sFrooHwADZccKwfoQwK2QHg= \
  --aad-client-app-id 8aaf8bd5-1bdd-4822-99ad-02bfaa63eea7 \
  --aad-tenant-id 72f988bf-0000-0000-0000-2d7cd011db47
```

From the [az aks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest) command list I didn't find an `edit` feature. So if I have created an AKS cluster, isn't there a way to set the `Azure AD` application IDs on the Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you can't change the parameters due to the fact that this requires RBAC and you can see in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/aad-integration) that a limitation is that once you create an non-RBAC cluster you can't modify it to be RBAC.

The way AKS (and EKS and GKE, although GKE allows you to modify more parameters) works is a complete control plane managed Kubernetes solution, so they can dictate whatever you can and cannot modify.

If you'd like to try AKS with AD I recommend creating a new cluster and if you have another older cluster without AD integration and running several workloads, you can move them gradually to the new cluster.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? You can login to the masters?  I can change my answer

Comment: ok, his wording confused me, i though he needed to update those, not set. the other answer is the proper one. just because something is in preview - doesnt mean you cant edit this. this answer is misleading and just happens to be correct

Comment: He wants to update all the `--aad-xxx` parameters as far as I understand. What does that have to do with enabling RBAC specifically? I mean you need RBAC for authentication, but adding the `--aad-xxx` parameters enables RBAC?

Comment: hmm, I read it, and I didn't see any mention of Azure Active Directory. I mean this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/troubleshooting#i-am-trying-to-enable-rbac-on-an-existing-cluster-can-you-tell-me-how-i-can-do-that).  Anyways, updated the answer...

Comment: read this first paragraph to the end: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/aad-integration. `Existing non-RBAC enabled AKS clusters cannot currently be updated for RBAC use.`

Comment: ahh, make sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

> Unfortunately enabling RBAC on existing clusters is not supported at
>   this time. You will need to explicitly create new clusters.

There is something you would want to know when you start to work with AKS. Follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/troubleshooting#i-am-trying-to-enable-rbac-on-an-existing-cluster-can-you-tell-me-how-i-can-do-that) to see more details.